# Angelscript - cast string to int

Tags: angelscript

I could use some help.  How do I explicity convert a string to an int.

Here is an example of what I would like to have working:

string string_num = "" + 1;

int num = cast(string_num);

I've tried searching the internet using the following:

"angelscript convert string to int"

"angelscript cast string to int"

"angelscript dictionary keys to int"

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/sdk/docs/manual/doc_script_stdlib_string.htm

```
int64 parseInt(const string &in str, uint base = 10, uint &out byteCount = 0)
```

so to convert, you'd just call `parseInt("1")`.

Converting from a string to a number is most often described as "parsing" which might be why your searches weren't coming up with anything.

Comment: Thank you very much for that response.  Yes you're correct.  Very appreciated.

Comment: If it's the correct answer, please mark it as correct by clicking on the tick in the left-hand side. Thanks!